# HashMap in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map

This is a `HashMap` implementation written in Python. All the methods are based on the [java implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) of a `HashMap`. Any and all critique is welcome.

This implementation is just a rewrite of some java `HashMap` methods. Yes, it's basically a wrapper class for pythons `dict`. This implementation is a simple exercise to see if I could write something from Java in Python.

```
from typing import Union, List

class HashMap:

    def __init__(self):
        self.capacity = 16
        self.map = {}

    def clear(self) -> None:
        """
        Clears all the entries into this hashmap

        :return: None
        """
        self.map = {}

    def contains_key(self, key: object) -> bool:
        """
        Returns if the map contains the passed key

        :param key -> object: Value to check residency in map keyset

        :return bool: True if "key" in map keyset, False otherwise
        """
        return key in self.map.keys()

    def contains_value(self, value: object) -> bool:
        """
        Returns if the map contains the passed value

        :param value -> object: Value to check residency in map valueset

        :return bool: True if "value" in map valueset, False otherwise
        """
        return value in self.map.values()

    def entry_set(self) -> set:
        """
        Returns a set of the hashmap

        :return set: A set representation of the map
        """
        return set(self.map)

    def get(self, key: object) -> Union[object, None]:
        """
        Returns the value at the passed key, None if not present

        :param key -> object: Key to retrieve value in map

        :return Union[object, None]: value at "key", None if key is not present in map
        """
        return self.map[key] if key in self.map.keys() else None

    def get_or_default(self, key: object, default_value: object) -> object:
        """
        Returns the value at the passed key, or default_value if not present

        :param key -> object: Key to retrieve value in map\n
        :param default_value -> object: Value to return if key is not present in map

        :return object: Value associated with "key", "default_value" otherwise 
        """
        return self.map[key] if key in self.map.keys() else default_value

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        """
        Returns if the map has no key-value entries

        :return bool: True if map isn't empty, False otherwise
        """
        return self.map != {}

    def key_set(self) -> set:
        """
        Returns a set of all the keys

        :return set: Set of all keys in map
        """
        return set(self.map.keys())

    def put(self, key: object, value: object) -> object:
        """
        Adds the key-value pair to the map, returning the value

        :param key -> object: Key to add to set\n
        :param value -> object: Value to add to set

        :return object: "value" passed
        """
        self.map[key] = value
        return value

    def remove(self, key: object) -> Union[object, None]:
        """
        Removes the mapping for the passed key, returning the value

        :param key -> object: Key to retrieve value from map

        :return object: Value associated with "key", None if key not in map keyset
        """
        if key in self.map.keys():
            value = self.map[key]
            del self.map[key]
            return value
        return None

    def size(self) -> int:
        """
        Returns the size of the hashmap

        :return int: Size of map
        """
        return len(self.map)

    def values(self) -> List[object]:
        """
        Returns a list of the values in the hashmap

        :return List[object]: List of values in map
        """
        return list(self.map.values())
```

Testing Implementation

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hashmap = HashMap()

    hashmap.put("Ben", 18)
    hashmap.put(5, 18)
    hashmap.put("5", True)
    hashmap.put(False, 3.661)

    print(hashmap.get(5))
    print(hashmap.get(False))
    print(hashmap.get("Ben"))
    print(hashmap.size())
    print(hashmap.values())
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this exercise -- is it to actually implement a hash map to get a better understanding of how they work (you haven't done that since you aren't hashing keys or mapping them to buckets), or is it to implement a Java-style interface over Python's hashmap (I don't think you've done that either; if nothing else you seem to be ignoring the `capacity` attribute which I assume would have some sort of meaning in Java-land), or is it something else?

Comment: @SamStafford I've provided some more description.

Comment: IMO this question shows no research effort, and so is worthy of downvotes. What do you expect to get out of a review? "This is an interface that doesn't utilize all the methods `dict` provides".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### *Refactoring the core interface:*

Since presented `HashMap` class is just a custom wrapper around Python's *dictionary* - it should borrow all the advantages from that.

As the class provides a public interface for the internal data structure - that data structure needs to be *protected* (or private). Otherwise, the one can easily compromise it like shown below:

```
hashmap = HashMap()
hashmap.map = tuple()
```

So we change the constructor/initializer to the following:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.capacity = 16
    self._map = {}
```

Let get down to instance methods:

- **`clear`** method. It reassigns the internal *map* with `self._map = {}`.
  In ideal perspective using `self._map.clear()` would be preferable as it allows to beat potential copies of `self._map` (even if that's unlikely to happen)
- **`contains_key`** method.
  Returns `key in self._map.keys()` which is a verbose way of **`key in self._map`**
- **`entry_set`** method and **`key_set`** method lead to confusion as they return the same result:
  `return set(self._map)` is technically equal to `return set(self._map.keys())`.

  To fix that - let's perceive "entry" as a `(key, value)` pair.
  Therefore the definition of `entry_set` is changed to:

  ```
  def entry_set(self) -> set:
      """
      Returns a set of the hashmap

      :return set: A set representation of the map
      """
      return set(self._map.items())
  ```
- **`get`** method. The noisy expression `self._map[key] if key in self._map.keys() else None` should be eliminated in favor of flexible [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

  ```
  self._map.get(key, None)
  ```
- **`get_or_default`** method has the same issue as `get` method, and the optimal way would be to just combine them into a single unified method:

  ```
  def get(self, key: object, default_value=None) -> object:
      """
      Returns the value at the passed key, or default_value if not present

      :param key -> object: Key to retrieve value in map\n
      :param default_value -> object: Value to return if key is not present in map

      :return object: Value associated with "key", "default_value" otherwise 
      """
      return self._map.get(key, default_value)
  ```
- **`is_empty`** method. The returned value `self._map != {}` is simply replaced with **`bool(self._map)`**
- **`key_set`** method. The returned value `set(self._map.keys())` is simplified to **`set(self._map)`**
- **`remove`** method. The whole method body:

  ```
  if key in self._map.keys():
      value = self._map[key]
      del self._map[key]
      return value
  return None
  ```

  can be replaced with the convenient [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) method:

  ```
  return self._map.pop(key, None)
  ```

---

The final optimized implementation:

```
class HashMap:

    def __init__(self):
        self.capacity = 16
        self._map = {}

    def clear(self) -> None:
        """
        Clears all the entries into this hashmap

        :return: None
        """
        self._map.clear()

    def contains_key(self, key: object) -> bool:
        """
        Returns if the map contains the passed key

        :param key -> object: Value to check residency in map keyset

        :return bool: True if "key" in map keyset, False otherwise
        """
        return key in self._map

    def contains_value(self, value: object) -> bool:
        """
        Returns if the map contains the passed value

        :param value -> object: Value to check residency in map valueset

        :return bool: True if "value" in map valueset, False otherwise
        """
        return value in self._map.values()

    def entry_set(self) -> set:
        """
        Returns a set of the hashmap

        :return set: A set representation of the map
        """
        return set(self._map.items())

    def get(self, key: object, default_value=None) -> object:
        """
        Returns the value at the passed key, or default_value if not present

        :param key -> object: Key to retrieve value in map\n
        :param default_value -> object: Value to return if key is not present in map

        :return object: Value associated with "key", "default_value" otherwise 
        """
        return self._map.get(key, default_value)

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        """
        Returns if the map has no key-value entries

        :return bool: True if map isn't empty, False otherwise
        """
        return bool(self._map)

    def key_set(self) -> set:
        """
        Returns a set of all the keys

        :return set: Set of all keys in map
        """
        return set(self._map)

    def put(self, key: object, value: object) -> object:
        """
        Adds the key-value pair to the map, returning the value

        :param key -> object: Key to add to set\n
        :param value -> object: Value to add to set

        :return object: "value" passed
        """
        self._map[key] = value
        return value

    def remove(self, key: object) -> Union[object, None]:
        """
        Removes the mapping for the passed key, returning the value

        :param key -> object: Key to retrieve value from map

        :return object: Value associated with "key", None if key not in map keyset
        """

        return self._map.pop(key, None)

    def size(self) -> int:
        """
        Returns the size of the hashmap

        :return int: Size of map
        """
        return len(self._map)

    def values(self) -> List[object]:
        """
        Returns a list of the values in the hashmap

        :return List[object]: List of values in map
        """
        return list(self._map.values())
```

P.S. obviously, Python's `dict` itself is a good *hashmap* :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a small review focusing only on the type hints.

- In all methods, the type of `key` should be [`Hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Hashable), not `object`. Unhashable objects (e.g. mutable collections like lists) cannot be used as keys in Python dictionaries, and the same goes for `HashMap` since it uses a Python dictionary behind the scenes.
- Instead of just using `set` as the return type, prefer using [`Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Set) with the type of the elements it contains:

  ```py
  def key_set(self) -> Set[Hashable]:
  ```
- Although they are equivalent, consider using `Optional[T]` instead of `Union[T, None]` as it is more readable:

  ```py
  def get(self, key: Hashable) -> Optional[object]:
  ```
- `__init__`'s return type should be `None`. After correcting this, you'll also need to provide a type hint for `self.map`:

  ```py
  def __init__(self) -> None:
      self.map: Dict[Hashable, object] = {}
  ```